# What is the notation for the n-dimensional bounded sample space?

Tags: probability, notation

Suppose that a multivariate continous random number $\xi$ distributes over an $n$-dimensional bounded sample space. The bound for the $i$-${th}$ dimension is $[a_i,b_i]$. In this case, is it correct to write this sample space as 
$$\Omega=\{\xi \in R^n| \xi_i \in [a_i,b_i],i=1,\dots,n\}?$$

Comment: Or $\prod _i^n [a_i,b_i]$ .  I wish Latex had a big X product symbol to use here, or  equivalently, I wish I could remember what it was.